# Show that the logical sentence $(p ↔ q) ↔ (p → q) ∧ (q → p)$ is a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve some truth-table problems, however, I still have difficulty setting up the table, so I'm not always sure that my line of reasoning led me to the solution of the problem.

**Problem:**

Show that the logical sentence $(p ↔ q) ↔ (p → q) ∧ (q → p)$ is a tautology

**What I tried:**

I created a truth table by adding all the variables, so I started doing the comparisons and getting the results

$$
\begin{array}{c c l}
p & q & p ↔ q & p → q & q → p & (p ↔ q) ↔ (p → q) &  (p ↔ q) ↔ (p → q) ∧ (q → p)  \text{}\\ \hline
T & T & T & T & T & T & T\text{}\\
T & F & F & F & T & T & T\text{}\\
F & T & F & T & F & F & F\text{}\\
F & F & T & T & T & T & T
\end{array}
$$

So, from my point of view, the sentence is *not a tautology*. I don't think that's wrong, however, maybe I'm wrong. So I wish someone could look at my table and tell me if I'm right about what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of operations is off. You want to show that $(p \leftrightarrow q) \leftrightarrow ((p \to q) \wedge (q \to p))$ is a tautology. (Note the extra parentheses to emphasise what happens when.)

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. It's a tautology now... Can I put my final answer for you to check and let me know if it's correct?

Comment: I suspect your new answer is correct---all the information is in your original table. Combine the fourth and fifth columns with $\wedge$ and you get precisely the second third column ($p \leftrightarrow q$)!